# Combing few side by side plots in one image till some given upper bound

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

For some time I'm thinking about one problem which I cannot solve. Let's say I want to plot side by side ggplots till some given number. I mean, let's say I want to have in one image four graphs, and if I want to have another graph it will be showed in next window. It's very easy to do it with standard plot, you just have to use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`. This command will plot four graphs in one image, and next one in another window. The problem with ggplot is that using command `plot_grid()`, `grid.arrange()` you do not specify amount of plots in one image, and fifth graph is included with previous ones.

To summarize : I'm searching for a command which can set upper bound of number of ggplots in one window analogous to `par(mfrow=c())`
Let's take for example :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10))
```

[image]

And I want to have :

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)     
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
```

[image]
[image]

Thank's in advance!

Comment: You could check this: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html

Comment: if you put your plots into a list, you could move along the list printing n plots at a time

Comment: Can you show me exactly the code you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with package `ggplus` that you can download from github.

```
devtools::install_github("guiastrennec/ggplus", force = TRUE)
```

The data set is given in the end.
First a graph with all facets.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplus)

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cat, ncol = 2)
g1
```

[image]

Now two graphs, each one with 2 gid of 2 by 2. Note that the last plot is incomplete, the plots titles can be removed in the usual way.

```
g2 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

facet_multiple(plot = g2, facets = "cat", ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]
[image]

**Data creation code.**

```
cat <- rep(letters[1:5], each = 10)
x <- y <- rep(1:10, 5)
df1 <- data.frame(x, y, cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Duck said, you should try `patchwork` instead of `grid.arrange`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
p=qplot(1:10,1:10)
p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

[image: plots in 2 columns]

```
p+p+p+p+p+p+p+p+plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

[image: plots in 3 columns]

More info on the [documentation website](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/layout.html#controlling-the-grid).

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for. You are just specifying certain layout but you do not split it into several images.